# How do I send data to a database if I just want to add a line that does not have its address?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-mvc

I create a film base. I have a method that adds another title to the film.

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/{id}/titles", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public
    void createTitles(
            @PathVariable final Long movieId,
            @RequestBody final Set<OtherTitle> titles
    ) {
        this.moviePersistenceService.saveOtherTitles(titles, movieId, this.authorizationService.getUserId());
    }
```

A sample film has a list of such titles

```
private Set<MovieOtherTitle> otherTitles;
```

but these objects (MovieOtherTitle) do not have their own addresses  to see them. `/othertitles/{id}` - There is no such thing, because it is not necessary at all.

So if I add a new title object to the database, but I do not set Location for this title, what should I set up the ResponseHeader and the returned method type?